# Retrofit 2 cancel request working

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I have been reading for a while about cancel request in retrofit 2.As far as i have read on cancel requests,onFailure() is called and request is  removed from the queue if not dispatched. But what happens if the request is already been dispatched(i know i'll get callback onFailure()) but does **Actual HTTP request** to the server is cancelled?

To elaborate let's say I am uploading an image to the server. Request has been dispatched and now cancel is called, I know I will get an onFailure callback for android but **will the image get uploaded to the server or will it be abandoned from the server side as well?**

This might be a basic thing in network requests but since this is my first time encounter not really aware how generally cancel requests works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `cancel` on retrofit's `Call` object will close the socket of the connection if connection has been established.

This means if you are in the middle of the file upload and you call the `cancel()` method, then the connection will immediately be closed and the file upload will fail.

But if you cancel the call when the file upload has completed and the server is sending response message, the file gets uploaded.

Comment: thank you. Any idea how to handle such tricky case you mentioned?

Comment: You might probably want to develop a acknowledgement system such as two-way handshake. But it will be too much complex. Such case occurs very rarely. I don't think you will need to handle such case.